# Texture2D implementation on iPhone problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, texture2d

Im trying draw text using Texture2D but all I get is a big white square. What wrong?

```
    glPushMatrix();

    glRotatef(rodar+30, 0, 1, 0);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);

    tex = [[Texture2D alloc] initWithString:@"imm" dimensions:CGSizeMake(2,1) alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter fontName:@"arial" fontSize:5];                    
    [tex drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 1)];
    [tex release];
        glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glPopMatrix();
```